# IIS does not appear to be serving ANY .net apps. The logs show a sc-win32-status of 5. What access is being denied?

Tags: asp.net, iis

The os is windows 2003 server. Using  ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 WITH ASP.NET MVC 2.

This is your typically freak event. I'm trying to run a ASP.NET MVC2 application on one of our development servers and it's like IIS never finishes the request. I created a completely blank web forms application and it does the same thing. The iis logs show a sc-win32-status of 5 for all of these attempts. It seems as though access is being denied, but I don't know why. All of the sites have the ASPNET user added to their security permissions.

Here's the crazy thing. For all pages I attempt to load I see output like this:

```
Url entered into browser: http://<server_name>:90/<app_name>/<app_name>.aspx

PlainURL: http://<server_name>:90/<app_name>/<app_name>.aspx
FirstPart: http://<server_name>
LastPart: :90/<app_name>/<app_name>.aspx
LastPart: /<app_name>/<app_name>.aspx
strSecure: https://<server_name>/<app_name>/<app_name>.aspx
```

Obviously replace  with the valid server name and  with the given name for the application. To add to this wonky tale, this happens for all urls entered even if they aren't apps under iis. Instead of saying the site isn't found, you get the above.

I've compared the IIS setup on this machine to another machine that is running fine and the setups look like they're perfectly duplicated. This goes for the web service extensions as well.

IIS does appear to server .asp & .html pages just fine.

**UPDATE 1**

I created a new web site (not virtual directory) in IIS and assigned it to port 91. .Net appears to work now. So this makes me rather confused as it's a work around, but doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that what ever is happening in IIS on port 90 is getting an access denied error. I don't know whose access this would pertain to or what to do to go about correcting it. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it is a problem with the port. 90 is NOT a standard port number.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Port 90 is the correct port in this case as our setup is wierd and port 80 is used for another web server (not IIS). If something is on port 90, it should get redirected to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

doh! SSL was being forced on the site and I wasn't aware of it. Turning that off in IIS resolved this issue.